# Why doesn't this way to get the left inverse work?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse, inverse-function

Consider $$f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, \, (x, \,y) \mapsto (x+2y, \, 2x-y).$$

I know that $f$ is bijective, so it's also injective and it has a left inverse $l$, which means that $l \circ f = Id_{\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}}$.

For any $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, $l(f(x,y))=(x,y)$ has to hold, so I thought I could determine $l$ like this:

$l(f(x,y))=(x,y) \Leftrightarrow l(x+2y, 2x-y) = (x,y)$.

This yields the linear system of equations $$\begin{align} x&+2y=x \\ 2x&-y=y \end{align}$$ which gives $x=y=0$, but I haven't learned anything about $l$.

I already know that $l$ is defined by $l: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, \, (x,\,y) \mapsto \left(\dfrac{2y+x}{5},\,\dfrac{2x-y}{5}\right)$, but why does my approach completely fail?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because you are implicitly claiming that $\ell$ sends $(x+2y,2x-y)$ to $(x+2y,2x-y)$; i.e., that $\ell$ is the identity. It would be like trying to find the value of $(x,y)$ that $f$ sends to $(3,5)$ by saying "$f(x,y)=(3,5)$, so $x=3$ and $y=5$", which of course is wrong. You have $\ell(x+2y,2x-y)=(x,y)$; that does *not* mean $x+2y=x$ and $2x+y=y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong step is when you go from $l(x+2y,2x-y) = (x,y)$ to $x+2y=x$ and $2x-y=y$. That's just not justified.

You know $f$ is surjective; so there is a value of $(x,y)$ that maps to $(3,5)$. So, we want to find $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)=(3,5)$. Using your step above, we would say "Oh, that means $x=3$ and $y=5$." Which of course is wrong. Instead, we need to *evaluate* $f(x,y)$ to $(x+2y,2x-y)$, and then set *that* equal to $(3,5)$, leading to $(x+2y,2x-y)=(3,5)$ and the equations $x+2y=3$ and $2x-y=5$.

So from $l(x+2y,2x-y)=(x,y)$, you would first need to replace the expression $l(x+2y,2x-y)$ by whatever its value is, then set *that* to $(x,y)$. But you don't know what $l(x+2y,2x-y)$ is in the first place! So you cannot do *that*.

You *could* do something as follows: you know that the function $l$ is linear, so there must exist constants $a,b,c,d$ such that $l(r,s) = (ar+bs, cr+ds)$. We just need to figure out $a,b,c,d$. So from 
$$l(x+2y,2x-y)=(x,y)$$
we get
$$\Bigl( a(x+2y) + b(2x-y), c(x+2y) + d(2x-y)\Bigr) = (x,y)$$
and solve for $a,b,c,d$.

However, that just amounts to finding the inverse of the usual matrix.

Comment: That made it very clear, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$f$ is represented by the matrix
$$F=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2\\2&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
can you find the inverse?

Your approach failed because your system search a fixed point of the transformation:
$$
F\vec x=\vec x
$$
not the inverse of the transformation that is given solving the system:
$$
F \vec x= \vec u
$$
with, in general, $\vec u \ne \vec x$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is not about how to get the inverse, I'm just curious about the fact that my approach failed and would like to know why.

Comment: I added to my answer. I hope it's useful :)